# Gdb: gcc -O0 assmbly exmple

Tags: gcc, assembly, gdb

Hopefully not a silly question.

Compiled without specifying optimization: gcc test.c -o test (which seem to chose -O0).

gcc -O2 or -O3 output much cleaner (at least it seems to me) assembly code than -O0.

What's the reason for -O0, how does it help us, I can't see that it's simpler than -O1 or -O2.

```
...
int sum(int x, int y)
{
    int sum = x + y;
    return sum;
}
...

0x00000000004004ed <+0>:     push   %rbp
0x00000000004004ee <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x00000000004004f1 <+4>:      mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
0x00000000004004f4 <+7>:      mov    %esi,-0x18(%rbp)
0x00000000004004f7 <+10>:    mov    -0x18(%rbp),%eax
0x00000000004004fa <+13>:    mov    -0x14(%rbp),%edx
0x00000000004004fd <+16>:    add    %edx,%eax
0x00000000004004ff <+18>:     mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
0x0000000000400502 <+21>:   mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
0x0000000000400505 <+24>:   pop    %rbp
0x0000000000400506 <+25>:   retq
```

Comment: It maps more directly to source code.

Comment: Some safety critical applications be it cars or aircraft or medical, etc may dictate that they dont want optimizations as it is too hard to validate that the compiler output correctly matched the source input.  its a moving target, where without optimizations, ideally, the toolchain can be validated, or is relatively easier, or there is more of a comfort level in the binary.

Comment: Also without optimization you can debug, single step, etc through the code where optimized dead code is removed, some code may be re-arranged, there isnt a one to one relationship between the high level and the output so you cant necessarily step, you cant necessarily watch memory or variables, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With optimizations turned off, there is a 1:1 representation between source code and machine code, allowing for easier debugging. With optimizations turned on, the compiler can do strange things like rearranging code or getting rid of variables that make debugging the code much harder.

Compiling with `-O0` is also typically faster as the optimizer is usually the slowest component of every modern compiler.